# jquery UI add/remove class duration not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery UI with the addClass/removeClass function. It is changing the class, but without the duration. Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--This has the Effects Core and all four boxes checked in the UI Core-->
<style type="text/css">    
.menu {
    height: 35px;
    padding: 15px 20px 5px 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    background: none;
}
.menu-hover {
    height: 35px;
    padding: 15px 20px 5px 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    background: url(../img/header-bg2.png) repeat-x;
}
</style>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu').hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass("menu-hover", 1000);
    }, function() {
      $(this).removeClass("menu-hover", 1000);
    });
  });
</script>

<a href="#"><div class="menu">Contact</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="menu">Services</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="menu">About</div></a>
<a href="index.html"><div class="menu">Home</div></a>
```

I have double-checked to make sure that it is indeed changing the class, and it is. Any ideas how to get the duration to work? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to add a duration? If you really want a "duration", do you mean `delay()`?

Comment: There's no duration parameter in both [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) methods.

Comment: I am trying to do [this](http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/addClass/#option-duration).

Comment: This is jQuery UI, not plain jQuery. http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/

Comment: Don't listen to these guys... JqueryUI has a method override of jQuery's built in `addClass`

Comment: Show the CSS for the menu-hover class. Maybe it doesn't have any styles that can be animated.

Comment: OK, then, am I missing something major here? Do I need a separate stylesheet (theme) for Jqury UI? I was under the impression jquery UI was just an extension of Jquery.

Comment: Rather embarrassing. I didn't put in the jquery UI link correctly. However, it is not animating to the new class, but making a delay before changing abruptly to the new class.

Comment: I haven't used jQuery UI myself, but I have a hard time visualising how it would animate between two background images. Try changing the height or color property in .menu-hover and see if that has an effect.

Comment: this should be used as default in the override, but perhaps explicityly defining your easing function will help in this case `("menu-hover", 1000,"swing");`

Comment: @MattStone It appears that it cannot animate between background images, only colors.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery UI will animate background colors, but not background images.

Source: Trial and error.

Comment: Makes sense, how could you logically animate between binary image data?

Answer (score 0):

For the delay, you can use jQuery's [**`delay()`**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$('.menu').hover(function() {
  $(this).delay(1000).addClass("menu-hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).delay(1000).removeClass("menu-hover");
});
```

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch I don't get you!

Comment: @preahkumpii What does `it` mean? Please update your question and give a comment here. :)

Comment: OKay, @preahkumpii Please update it in the question. And I have given you a suggestion using [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/). Will that work for you?